# I cannot translate the text in twig files

Tags: php, internationalization, twig, translation

I am using twig files for some of the forms in my PHP application. I did everything following this link

> http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html#

which tells how twig files can be translated using Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n. I believe i have followed all the steps but still i cannot seem to solve the problem.

This is how my PHP code looks like

```
require_once 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$twig_loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(APP_PATH . 'corporate/views');
$GLOBALS['twig'] = new Twig_Environment($twig_loader, array(
    'cache' => TMP_PATH . 'twig_cache',
    'debug' => DEBUG,
    'auto_reload' => true
));
$GLOBALS['twig']->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());


return $GLOBALS['twig']->
        render('path/to/twig/template'.$formTemplate,
            array_merge($formVariables,
                array(
                    "help" => isset($helpbox) ? $helpbox : array(),
                    "type" => $current_data['type'],
                    "integration_id" => $current_data['action_comp'],
                    "automation_type" => $current_data['automation_type']
                )
            )
        );
```

There is another PHP file where i read all the twig files and run the following command as following.

```
$exe = 'xgettext --force-po --default-domain emarketeer --keyword="pgettext:1c,2" -c -j -o /tmp/messages.po '.escapeshellarg($file).' >/dev/null 2>&1';
system($exe);
```

this is how my twig template ($formTemplate) looks like

> {% extends 'integrations/_mixed/automation_form_wrapper.twig' %}
>
> {% block formular %} {% import "_utils/form.twig" as form %}
>
> {{ form.boxlabel( 'Name (choose automation Name)'|trans, "Name") }}
>
> {{ form.input("action_name", action_name.value, "", "",
>   action_name.collection ) }}
>
> {% endblock %}

The imported twig template ('_utils/form.twig') as form looks like this

> {% macro boxlabel(label, label_for, tooltip, class, extra) %}     {% set
>   label_parts = label|split("\n") %}          {{- label_parts[0] -}}      {% if tooltip %}                     {% endif %}         {% if label_parts[1] %}
>             {{ label_parts[1]}}        {%
>   endif %}   {% endmacro %}
>   {% macro input(name, value, type, class, extra) %}
>       
>   {% endmacro %}

Can anyone please tell me if i am missing something. There will be a lot of code which i cannot defin or explain but i hope i have delivered the idea and the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.